# How do I use cookies in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails and just finished reading a major part of the Agile book. I wonder why they don't mention cookies in the book.

Also, I would like to get quick explanation about cookies in rails.

Comment: Cookies are used a lot in background.  Maybe, it will be interesting to read this guide http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are built-in and easy. Read the section on sessions.